# How to convert import file from Excel into xts file in R studio

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

I'am working in performanceAnalytics package in R studio. My task is to do matrix-based optimal portfolio. But R-studio constantly throw me an error when I'm trying to use this or similar codes: `chart.Bar(portfelj_sa_Bitcoinom$CROBEX)`. R-studio tells me:

> The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.

I suppose that I need to convert my existing file into Xts but I don't know how to do that since I'm a beginner in this program.

I tried to convert file into Xts using code from websites. But since I'm new in this program I don't know to use them properly. I will show you my file structure.

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   48 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date   : POSIXct, format: "2018-07-13" "2018-07-20" "2018-07-27" "2018-08-03" ...
 $ CROBEX : num  1808 1792 1834 1823 1837 ...
 $ BUX    : num  35642 35187 35944 36760 36171 ...
 $ BETI   : num  7933 7898 8041 8089 8154 ...
 $ WIG    : num  2157 2183 2291 2287 2247 ...
 $ BITCOIN: num  6238 7354 8165 7434 6185 ...

Date                CROBEX    BUX  BETI   WIG BITCOIN


  <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2018-07-13 00:00:00  1808. 35642. 7933. 2157.   6238.
2 2018-07-20 00:00:00  1792. 35187. 7898. 2183.   7354.
3 2018-07-27 00:00:00  1834. 35944. 8041. 2291.   8165.
4 2018-08-03 00:00:00  1823. 36760  8089. 2287.   7434.
5 2018-08-10 00:00:00  1837. 36171. 8154. 2247.   6185.
6 2018-08-17 00:00:00  1818. 36437. 8185. 2218.   6581.
2019-05-03 00:00:00  1844. 41775. 8443. 2319.   5768.
2 2019-05-10 00:00:00  1841. 41068. 8305. 2192.   6379.
3 2019-05-17 00:00:00  1865. 39878. 8224. 2184.   7344.
4 2019-05-24 00:00:00  1877. 40023. 8189. 2188.   7987.
5 2019-05-31 00:00:00  1851. 40904. 8493. 2239.   8574.
6 2019-06-07 00:00:00  1875. 41160. 8576. 2281.   8044.
```

How can I proceed using my data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your dataframe to an xts object like this:

```
library(xts)
data <- xts(data[,-1], order.by = data[,1])
```

This tells xts to create an object using the first column as the index. Then, it should work as you expect.